# How to run a Azure build pipeline and download a dependency which is not available in Maven repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sapjco3

Trying to deploy an MULE API and as CI/CD I am using Azure Build Pipeline, but we are getting following error :

```
 Failed to execute goal on project mule-fts-sap-eapi: Could not resolve dependencies for project 1674d8b0-3a4f-4bfb-8c70-89641e023735:mule-fts-sap-eapi:mule-application:1.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.sap.conn.jco:com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3:jar:3.0.19, com.sap.conn.idoc:com.sap.conn.idoc.sapidoc3:jar:3.0.13, com.sap.conn.jco:libsapjco3:dll:3.0.19: Could not find artifact com.sap.conn.jco:com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3:jar:3.0.19 in Central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) ->
```

We found this dependency not in Maven repo, so what could be the possible way to download this dependency from azure pipeline?

We tried to put the .zip file of dependency in Azure library and but not sure how to pull it, is it possible to store the .zip file of dependency to store somewhere in azure pipeline and unzip and use it when required.

Comment: The question is about how to install SAP dependencies in a Maven repository for an Azure pipeline. There is no relationship to Mule in this question.

Comment: Hi Niladri, what is the latest status of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the [Maven Authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/maven-authenticate?view=azure-devops) before you resolve the artifacts?

```
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    artifactsFeeds: '**'
```

[image]